# Different cultures different calculations in c#?

Tags: c#, internationalization, culture

In my algorithm I read an excel file which contains data from a data set. I process these excel files and I convert them to double (or I use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 to read the excel file). Then, I normalize this data set to [0,1].

But, there is a strange result. In a PC which has *date, time and number format* in English(United States) it produces other results comparing to a PC with Turkish *date, time and number format*.

I use Threads, Parallel.For loops and Tasks in my application. I read somewhere that Threads do not inherite the culture (something like this but I could not understand).

It came very strange to me. Did someone face such a problem?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the decimal and thousands seperators. In lots of countries the decimal seperator is a "," instead of "." in english.

Comment: Yes it has to do with that but which one is right? Turkish format uses "," as a decimal point while English (United States) uses "." as a decimal separator. Now, which one should I use? English(United States)?

Comment: It depends on the locale of the current system you are running on. So there is no right or wrong. How do you get the data from excel? I guess there is a problem with that f.e. it gives you "." or "," even if you have a different locale. I guess the string conversation to double is the critical part where the problem happens.

Comment: Just stick to one convention and use that. Turkish is as good as anything, and the Turkish-language edition of Excel expects comma `,` as does string parsing and formatting in .NET with Turkish `CultureInfo` (`"tr-TR"`).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I am not changing the Culture of my application when I use a PC with Turkish settings. I use the default CultureInfo of .NET. Is it possible that my application by default uses en-US ( "." as a decimal seperator) in all the machines, no matter what the machine`s culture is?

Comment: Do you mean http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx ?
If you don´t specify anything it should use the current Culture of the system.

Comment: Well it is very strange. I do not specify anything else. I have thousands of rows in c# and I am pretty sure that I have never used Culture or changed it.

Comment: @HectorLector I installed my app in a PC with Turkish settings and in Control Panel I changed "," to "." and now it works same as in my PC. This is driving me mad :S